# Django-photologue - upload images from frontend?

Tags: django, photologue

Is there any way to upload images using photologue from the front end rather than through the admin page?

If not, is there a suggestion for a better django package? Something that allows for the storing and retrieving of large numbers of photos from the frontend.

Comment: You can use the same forms that it uses in the admin in your own views; or do you mean something else?

Comment: No that answers my question perfectly. Could you elaborate a bit more on how to do that? (I'm still fairly new to django)